# Google Sheets: How to link to another sheet within workbook by sheet name

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to link to another sheet within a Google Sheets workbook using the target's sheet name?

I've seen other posts that show how to do this but they rely on getting the sheet's gid. I can't use that because I need this to work in Excel and Google Sheets and my workbooks are being created dynamically with a Node script.

In Excel I can write =HYPERLINK("#'NameOfSheet'!A1", "Click here"). But this doesn't work in Google Sheets. It creates a link but when you click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use the sheet's URL instead, to link to other sheet or tab. Just for example:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10HufqWRKiK_iR45Z52ABTiba0Lq1wVMIRxdefSI3NA/edit#gid=0", "Link text here")
```

Notice that this also changes when you link to another tab:

```
#gid=0
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that the workbooks are being created dynamically with a script, so I won't know the sheet's URL in advance to pass that to the cell. That's why I was hoping to pass the sheet name because I'll at least know that

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a way to have this work in Google Sheets and Excel, so something like the tab names would still work, but a specific Google URL wouldn't work in Excel

Comment: @Cineno28 excel and google sheets are two completely different platforms. Especially in your case, same solution for both platforms does not exist. Think about it, google-sheets is an online platform while excel is offline. Google sheets needs a URL to redirect you to a sheet, excel runs locally so it does not require that. If you want two solutions then you should post two different posts.

Comment: Hi there @Cineno28 ! I am also studying your issue, but I don't understand why this solution doesn't fulfill your goals. When you say that *the workbooks are being created dynamically with a script*, could you please share the script used so we all can take a look? ALso, please help me understand why this solution is not enough for you.